# show() is undefined because of custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I wrote this plugin to catch show event only for div_loading_page element:

```
(function ($) {
        $.each(['show'], function (i, ev) {
            var el = $.fn[ev];
            $.fn[ev] = function () {

                this.each(function () {
                    if (this.id == 'div_loading_page') {
                        $(this).trigger(ev);
                        return false; // break out of the loop
                    }
                });
                //alert(this.id);
                el.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

It's working fine but because of it i get following error:

$cluetipTitle.show() is undefined , which is from cluetip jquery plugin. Any idea how can i resolve this conflict?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Override jQuery's show function?

Comment: By doing this i catch event of show, like when div_loading_page being visible through out my app. This allows me to write $('#div_loading_page').bind('show', function () {...});

Comment: should also change to `return el.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: ya did it worked, sry mistakenly marked wrong answer as right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
el.apply(this, arguments);
```

To

```
return el.apply(this, arguments);
```

This ensure that the original function's return value is reserved and will not cause unexpected behavior

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
$.each(['show']
```

to

```
return $.each(['show']
```

this will allow for chaining, ie doing what you want to do with the .show